# Google drive api python - How to download all the files inside a folder or the folder to a specific local destination path

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I need to download all the files inside a drive folder or the folder itself and save them in a specific local destination, my actual code is here:

```
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.folder']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    
    file_id = '1qQ8hOSudoo7ISwqSAOeqsuBdsh-ZFCqm'
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but it is throwing the following error, also i dont know how to set a specific local destination

```
"HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1qQ8hOSudoo7ISwqSAOeqsuBdsh-ZFCqm?alt=media returned "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.". Details: "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.">"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) setting parent to the file id of the directory you are looking for.

Then loop through each file returned and download it using the code you have now.

```
  file_id = [File id from first call]
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

If you are looking for a method which will do it for you you wont find one.  You will need to download them one at a time.